# XQuery Avg function only giving average of single element

Tags: database, xquery, saxon

So I am brand new to XQuery and trying to use the Avg function to get the average GPA of some students. So for students $s I return avg($s/GPA) but this just gives me a huge list of all students and their individual GPA's (which I assume are averaged and therefore the same). Here is the actual code:

```
    <T> {
  for $s in doc("ComS363/UniversityDatasets/Student.xml")/Students/Student
    return
   <AverageGPA> {avg($s/GPA)} </AverageGPA>
    } </T>;
```

When I get the result list it is just a long list as follows rather than a single result:

```
<AverageGPA> 2.91 </AverageGPA> 
<AverageGPA> 3.91 </AverageGPA>
<AverageGPA> 4.0 </AverageGPA> 
<AverageGPA> 3.22 </AverageGPA>
<AverageGPA> 1.31 </AverageGPA> 
<AverageGPA> 3.60 </AverageGPA>
  ....and so on......
```

I know that it is probably a stupid mistake/something I am missing but at 3 AM I just can't figure it out. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're now calling avg() for each student, you should call it once for all students:

```
avg(doc("ComS363/UniversityDatasets/Student.xml")/Students/Student/GPA)
```